# Может ли Сервер вызвать метод клиента ?

Tags: gwt, java

Предполагается, что клиент на **java** в **GWT** уже вызывал сервер (вызов метода и асинхронный ответ сервера).

Может ли сервер **идентифицировать** обращавшихся к нему клиентов и **по своей инициативе** вызвать клиента (передать ему данные) ?

Возможно я плохо искал в Сети, но сложилось впечатление, что это невозможно.

Comment: У вас сложилось почти верное впечатление. Это потому, что HTTP имеет свою специфику.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть comet заключается в том, что клиент подключается к серверу, запрос проходи и сервер начинает отвечать... и всё отвечает и отвечает и не заканчивает ответ долго-долго. Можно хоть целую вечность держать открытым соединение. При этом, сервер в любой момент может дописать в ответ что-нибудь и клиент сразу же получит ответ (если сеть работает подобающим образом, разумеется), без задержки (кроме задержки сети).

Раз вы используете GWT и Java на сервере, то логично использовать [GWT-comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/). Собственно, [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/wiki/GettingStarted).

Чтобы лучше понять принцип, можете прочесть Ajax for Java developers: [Write scalable Comet applications with Jetty and Direct Web Remoting](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jettydwr/). Эта статья рассчитана на Jetty и не описывает клиентскую сторону, но объясняет как работает Comet.

Comment: Огромное спасибо !

Буду изучать.

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно. Я вижу два способа.

1. Опрос сервера по таймеру.
2. Оставить открытое соединение. При необходимости передать ответ, в котором будет набор команд для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Второе называется comet.

Comment: Спасибо !  

С 1. все ясно, и по понятным причинам не очень интересно (я имею в виду случай, когда сервер отвечает на запрос без задержки).

Про 2. пока не очень понятно. Если можно, поподробнее. Не понятен алгоритм  метода (методов) сервера.

При продолжении обсуждения, я буду дополнять (править, **UPD**) вопрос. Это правильно ?

Comment: @avp Да, это правильно.